# Separating images from the apk file in android

Tags: android, apk

I am writing an android application which has a lot of images in it.

I do not want to keep these images as a part of my apk file because that will make the size of the apk file very huge.
I have written the application in a way that it loads these images at runtime from the sdcard from some predefined location. Now my problem is that how do i provide these images to the user who wants to install my application. Since the images are not a part of the project (i.e. not present in any of the drawable folders) so they will not be a part of the APK file that i provide.

Is it even possible to do such a thing in Android? Or can someone suggest a better solution that i have right now. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Most media-heavy games download files from the server the first time you run them. I don't know much about it besides that, except that the play store has some kind of apk size limit.

Comment: Many early to present games is using such technique. (include but not limited to Android). They launch a splash and detect the assets are up-to-date or not, and download from server. For Android, you can just use HTTPClient to download the assets and save to SD Card.

Comment: GGG and xandy I am not looking for a solution that involves loading images from some webserver. But thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an official way to achieve what you want: [**APK Expansion Files**](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/expansion-files.html)

Comment: Thanks for a quick response. I have not explored this concept yet but it looks very close to what i want to do. I will explore this option more and will update. Thanks again!!!

Comment: Cristian, this was the exact thing i was looking for. Thanks